# Can two different topologies have the same basis?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces, self-learning

I started general topology recently, and a partner of mine made a example of two different topologies generated by the same basis, so I'd like to know if that is possible, and if it is not, to see a proof of it.

Comment: This is not possible.  It would be most helpful to actually see the details of this partner's example.

Comment: Just consider an arbitrary open set in one of the topologies, represent it using the basis, and then it is also an element of the other topology by definition of a basis.

Comment: Not if they are topologies on the same set. If they are topologies on different sets... well, one usually speaks of a basis in *context* (as, "a subset of the power set of $X$"), so one would not normally call them "the same basis".

Comment: Obviously if you are saying that your partner did it, then it is possible, so then there is nothing to ask.